# xmlserializer - what properties can be set?

Tags: android, properties, xml-serialization

How do I find out what properties can be set for XmlSerializer?

In particular, I'd like to set the line break and indentation.  I found a post that gave an example for that, but it caused an unsupported property exception.

Answer (score 1):

When using XmlSerializer in Android, you should use this get line-break and indentation:

```
xmlSerializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I ended up not using XmlSerializer so I probably won't get around to trying this.  Points anyway.